# two barcode formats at the same time

Tags: java, android, zxing

I am using a QR code scan library zxing.
Is there a way to use multiple bar code formats at the same time?

EXAMPLE)
ONE_D_CODE_TYPES And DATA_MATRIX

```
ScanOptions options = new ScanOptions();
//like this
options.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(ScanOptions.ONE_D_CODE_TYPES);
options.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(ScanOptions.DATA_MATRIX);

options.setPrompt("Scan a barcode");
options.setCameraId(0);  // Use a specific camera of the device
options.setBeepEnabled(false);
options.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Just guessing that these are int flags: `options.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(ScanOptions.ONE_D_CODE_TYPES | ScanOptions.DATA_MATRIX);` Javadoc should provide the definitive answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use both of them using `|` character. Try this to use both of them:

```java
options.setBarcodeFormats(ScanOptions.ONE_D_CODE_TYPES | ScanOptions.DATA_MATRIX);
```

Comment: sorry..  it doesn't work.

Comment: then try this code. I edited it

Comment: I'm sorry, the code hasn't been edited;;

Comment: What does `the code hasn't been edited` mean @서태우?